# Postman Canary 8.0.0-canary01 not saving environment variables

Tags: json, variables, postman, environment

Today I upgraded my Postman to the latest version, going from PostmanCanary 7.37.0-canary01 to 8.0.0-canary01.

I used to run a login request and save the returned access token to my environment variables with this script:

```
response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
access_token = response.access_token;
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access_token",access_token);
```

to process this response :

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1610147694",
    "not_before": "1610143794",
    "resource": "https://xxxxxxxxxxx.crm.dynamics.com/",
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxI1NiIsIng1dCI6IjVPZjlQNUY5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1EayIsxxxxZCI6IjxxxxxxxxxxxxNDd0NtxxxxxxxxxEREUS1Exxxx.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.EXV9P_DZIdVbTUK4PY6VcyrUmUx752ZA9MGr5BJ7xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxX5wgidfGfoNklllZuoJVTi91jtnKP2T9Q-XFShpXhexDdCgOvMe9ZOOd0vOb11of1YPl37GKILtHikT3oPvKfUjBhOjZkFJo6F7pKeuxa3XiD_3WM1eCurVzuaG9iME94mFXb3HNTgUrWw9mPEqDwVzfxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxy0lw-2EcqpEYk7fqHUOTPUfAj2426zVV7ITfFPLdN08c4OND336sXpKjEFa5c7Buyk1dc24nawqJwCoKve1DaZAwPwljZKhGIIW4rd-1nitik2xWg"
}
```

Even if the environment variables did not exist prior to the call, this script would create them and set values. If I opened the environment variables, it would be listed.

After the upgrade, this no longer works. My subsequent requests kept failing because an old access_token was still there as it was not getting updated. I deleted the old access_token and confirmed that the access_token is now no longer being created.

I read about the resulting parsed JSON causing issues for other people because it is not text. I don't truly believe this to be the issue, mine is a single value, not a structure nor an array, but decided to play it safe and stringify it. Following the current documentation, I changed my script to :

```
response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
access_token = response.access_token;
console.log (access_token);   // I can see the token in the console - parsing executed correctly
pm.environment.set("access_token",JSON.stringify(access_token)); // setting the environment variable
console.log(pm.environment.get("access_token")); // getting the exact same environment variable I have just set - I can see this on the console as well
console.log("WTF?!?!?");  // Self explanatory - added at the end to ensure all instructions in the script are read and executed - I see this every time as well
```

This does not work either (with or without stringify) and gives me the same results. Everything seems fine on the console, but when I look at my environment variables, access_token is not present although I can access it during the execution of the test script. Afterward, it is gone.

At this point I'm frustrated and at a loss - have anyone else seen similar behavior or am I missing something stupidly simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please use stable postman version :

https://www.postman.com/downloads/

Canary builds usually for beta testing , the issue seems to be there and i have raised a bug:https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9412

Update The issue is fixed now : https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/9412

Comment: Thank you, I have done that. Glad to know the issue was confirmed.

Comment: @HardieBotha thank you the issue is fixed now